# Error beep from backslash key '\', Unable to use as localleader. Gvim Windows 8

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to use the backslash key `\` as the local leader.  I have done this before in other vim environments but on my windows pc the backslash key just makes an error sounding beep.

I have tried to mess with ttimeout but I don't think that is the problem.  I can use my Leader key `,` just fine.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You might be interested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16110145/4194289). It is about MacVim but I think it is also relevant for gVim with windows.

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem with Vi.  It was a problem with me.

As the question statox referenced discusses, the beep is because there are no commands using the backslash key.

In my case, this was because the ftplugin I was trying to use had not been loaded correctly.  After fixing that all worked OK